# ブラウザで操作を早く行うとJavascriptの関数が起動しない

Tags: javascript

Javascriptで構築しているサイトで
どうしても原因がわからない事象があり質問させていただきます。

ブラウザにテーブルデータを一覧表示し、
プルダウン選択で値を変更すると、
live関数を起動しデータ更新処理を実行する
仕組みなのですが、プルダウンの操作を早く行うとlive関数が
起動せずにデータ更新が漏れてしまいます。
ゆっくり操作すると問題無く起動します。
また、この事象はブラウザによって動作が異なり、
FireFox、IEで発生するのですが、Chromeでは発生しません。

事象がランダムに発生するので原因がわかりません。
何か考えられる理由はあるでしょうか？
もしわかる方いましたらご教示ください。

環境
・jquery-1.6.2
・WEBサーバ：Apache
・DB：MySQL

Comment: [「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考に問題が再現するコードを質問に記載すると、回答が得られやすいです。

Comment: 「操作を早く」とは何に対して早いのでしょうか。ページロード? プルダウンを開いてからの時間? live() が呼ばれる前にプルダウンが操作されるとダメ、というのが典型的な問題です。

Answer (score 1):

## 仮定

回答としてはエスパーですが、想像力たくましく質問文を解釈してみました。

- ページ表示直後に JavaScript の機能が適用されているプルダウンメニューを操作しても、JavaScript の機能が働かない。

## コード

```js
'use strict';
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
  event.target.querySelectorAll('#sample select').forEach(function (select) {
    select.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
    }, false);
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<p>(...膨大なコンテンツ...)</p>

<form id="sample">
  <p>
    <select name="alphabet">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select name="number">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</form>

<p>(...膨大なコンテンツ...)</p>
```

## 解説

前述のコードは DOMContentLoaded まで実行を待ちます。
従って、DOMContentLoaded が発火するまでは JavaScript の機能が使えず、Webページを表示直後にselect要素の選択操作を行った場合に console.log への出力機能が働かない可能性があります。
JavaScript による DOM 参照は DOM が構築されてから働くものなので、DOM 構築は先出しする必要があります。
その為、「静的HTML + JavaScript」では表示直後の操作に完全な対応が出来ないのが実情です。

## 対策

対策は大別して2つあります。

- JavaScript の機能が適用されるまで操作不可能にする
- JavaScriptで要素ノードを生成する

前者は該当要素に **disabled属性** を付与する事で操作不可能な状況を作り出します。
後者は `createElement` 等のAPIでノードを動的に生成し、イベント定義してからノードを挿入する事で表示直後の操作に対応させます。

Re: @hosayu